# how do i select light-weight 6dof robot?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, design, industrial-robot, platform

I plan to do some scientific research, after modeling and path planning for the robot, The algorithm outputs the Joint control torque(or Joint variable), and then i want to input this result to the robot Control platform to check my algorithm, as far as I know, most robot can only provide point-to-point tracking instructions(NOT torque\joint variable input API),any robot can supports torque or joint variable as the robot input(when i input joint variable or torque, robot can move)?

How can I program a 6 DOF robot using torque rather than joint positions as input?

If you have any questions or concerns, don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you just want a recommendation for a 6 dof robot that supports torque on a joint as input?

Comment: @Eric Lavigne yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article explains how to implement joint-torque control on top of position-controlled robots.

Implementing Torque Control with High-Ratio Gear Boxes and without Joint-Torque Sensors
https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01136936/document

Copied from another StackExchange question:

https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/7531/18316

Comment: this one can supports torque or joint variable as robot input?